# How to read content from accessibilityService when there is no TextView?

Tags: android, accessibilityservice

I'm trying to read the article name in the BBC news app on Android. I've created an `accessibilityService` to read screen contents. I loop over all views found and print the `node.toString()` and any `node.getText().toString()` that it may have for all child views to. I cannot find any `TextView` with the name of the article in it.

I know its possible to extract because Google TalkBack reads out the article fine. Does anyone know how its been hidden and I can view this ?

The settings of my `accessibilityService` are shown below

```
<accessibility-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeAllMask"
    android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackGeneric"
    android:accessibilityFlags="flagDefault|flagReportViewIds"
    android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
    android:description="@string/service_description"
    android:notificationTimeout="1000"/>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's simple, likely just a bug on your part, but you've only provided your service configuration, which suggests you believe the bug is there.  This is doubtful, you could potentially add "flagIncludeNotImportantViews" but I doubt this will help, as any view with text is likely considered important.  You should supply some other code as well.  This is actually pretty easy, but you're forcing us to speculate on where your bug might be...

Answer (score -1):

```
JSONObject getTextViews(AccessibilityNodeInfo info)  {
  if(info!=null){
      JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
      try {
          jsonObject.put("Class:",""+info.getClassName());

      if(info.getClassName().equals("android.widget.TextView")){
           jsonObject.put("Text",""+info.getText());
         // Log.d("TextViews:", ""+info.getText());
          return jsonObject;
      }else {
          JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
         for(int i=0;i<info.getChildCount();i++){
            array.put(getTextViews(info.getChild(i)));
         }
         jsonObject.put("Child",array);
      }
      } catch (JSONException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }

      return jsonObject;
  }else
      return null;
}
```

This is a recursive function to get the whole layout on the foreground window in form of a `Json Hierarchy`. Just pass the `root` `AccessibilityNodeInfo` `object`. Call this function in `onAccessibilityEvent` of your service and use `EventType` `AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_CONTENT_CHANGED`.